# How to replace lookup based on row names when using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

It has been stated several times that dplyr will drop rownames, and now version 0.3 has done so.

I have often used row names to translate between different identifiers kept in a data frame like this:

```
test <- data.frame(Greek = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"), Letters = LETTERS[1:3])
rownames(test) <-test$Letters
lookup <- c("C", "B")
test[lookup, "Greek"]
[1] Gamma Beta 
Levels: Alpha Beta Gamma
```

Due to a lack of rownames this now fails with dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
test <- tbl_df(data.frame(Greek = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"), Letters = LETTERS[1:3]))
rownames(test) <-test$Letters
lookup <- c("C", "B")
test[lookup, "Greek"]
Source: local data frame [2 x 1]

 Greek
1    NA
2    NA
```

I've tried using filter() and select(), but couldn't find a solution which preserves the order of the lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one time where you can play with `match`es:

```
test[match(lookup,test$Letters),"Greek"]
[1] Gamma Beta 
Levels: Alpha Beta Gamma
```

And you can wrap in a `do` to make it dplyr-ic:

```
test %>% do(`[`(.,match(lookup,.$Letters),)) %>% select(Greek)
Source: local data frame [2 x 1]

  Greek
1 Gamma
2  Beta
```

Or as @hadley mentions, `left_join` does what you are looking for:

```
left_join(data.frame(Letters=lookup),test) %>% select(Greek)
Joining by: "Letters"
  Greek
1 Gamma
2  Beta
```

Comment: The dplyr-ic version is not exactly what I'd call beautiful code, but both versions seem to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: Or better, use `left_join()` or `inner_join()`

Comment: @hadley `inner_join` seems to re-order, but `left_join` does what the OP wants.

Comment: If `inner_join` reorders, that's a bug.

Comment: I've submitted dplyr issue #684.